# how to add http headers like access_token in GraphiQL UI

Tags: graphql, loopback4, graphiql

i am using graphiQL Ui with my loopback4 framework but i can't see http headers to add access_key in graphiQL UI. my rest api's are authorized by access_token now i have question how can i add access_token with my query.

[image: GraphiQL Ui]

please tell me how can i add access_token with my query. thanks

i just install npm i --save openapi-to-graphql-cli and run my loopback4 application with npm start and then in different terminal i run npx openapi-to-graphql-cli --port=3001 http://localhost:3000/openapi.json. after that i open browser and start graphql server by using http:localhost:3001/graphql

Comment: Maybe you are using an older version of GraphiQL? There should be an option `"headers"` right next to the `"variables"` section.

Comment: Actually i am testing my graphQL queries in postman. postman also give environment to test graphQL queries. i am giving access_token when i run graphQL query but it shows unauthorized

Comment: and how can i upgrade graphiQL UI. because i just install openapi-to-graphql-cli.